# Zurb Foundation Using the space either side of a 12 column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have developed a site using Zurb Foundation which is of course 12 columns wide.

I want to be able to put adverts either side of my content if it is wide enough, else show it below. I can figure out the last bit, of moving it elsewhere if there is not enough room.

An example is like so: [Zurb Template](http://foundation.zurb.com/prototype-example3.php)

I have tried floated divs before the container (under the header etc.), however these are always butted right up against the browser window. I'd like it to float left, then float right within this, so it is next to the content so I can apply padding/margin to keep them a set distance from the content.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Really difficult to understand what you need here. Are you trying to position ads outside of your 12 column layout? I'd recommend adding some of your code to the post so we can see what you're doing. Making a codepen (at codepen.io) would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a "cleaner" way, but I'd just solve this by using absolute positioning.
Some quick pseudo code to show how you could do it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div style="position: relative;">
       <div id="adsL-container">L ads here</div>
       <div id="adsR-container">R ads here</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row #adsL-container, .row #adsR-container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 300px;
}
.row #adsL-container {
   left: -300px;
}
.row #adsR-container {
   right: -300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-2 columns hide-for-small ads">
 ...
</div>
<div class="large-8 columns small-12 columns">
..
 </div>
<div class="large-2 columns hide-for-small ads">
...
 </div>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns show-for-small ads">
 ...
</div>
    <div class="small-12 columns show-for-small ads">
 ...
</div>
```

use class="hide-for-small" to hide div for larger screens